# What is the cardinality of $\omega^\omega$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I have started reading about Baire Space as a prerequisity for the subject of Borel hierarchies. And if I understand correctly, Baire space is $\omega^\omega$ (The space of all functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$)?
I guess the Topology on this space is the product topology?
also, Can I assume that the cardinality of $\omega^\omega$ is $\aleph_0$ as a countable union of countable sets $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \omega^k$?.

If the answer is yes, Then, what is the first ordinal that has cardinality $\aleph_1$.
Also, is anyone familiar with a good source for studying Borel hierarchy (That also contain exercises if possible..)?

Thanks!!
Shir

Now that I think of it, Baire space should also contain uncountable sequences.. so, what is the cardinality of $\omega^\omega$? is it $\aleph_0$ or $\aleph_1$?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\omega^\omega$ is not the ordinal exponentiation, but rather the set of all functions from $\omega$ to itself. It is easy, and I leave it to you, to verify that this is in fact a set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (if you give up, it has been asked on this site infinitely many times before), so definitely not $\aleph_0$, but not necessarily $\aleph_1$ either if you don't assume more than just $\sf ZFC$.

So you shouldn't assume that this is a countable set (you can, but equally you can just assume that $0=1$ or something). The set that you suggest, which is the eventually zero sequences, is a countable set which is also dense. This set witnesses the fact that the Baire space is a separable space.

For the Borel hierarchy basic books about descriptive set theory such as Kechris' and Moschovarkis' books can be good. Jech's **Set Theory** also has a chapter with the basic information in the first part.

Also, the first ordinal of size $\aleph_1$ is no other than $\omega_1$. We cannot represent it in a better way using ordinal arithmetic because ordinal arithmetic preserves cardinality, so $\alpha^\beta+\gamma\cdot\delta+\eta$ is countable if all $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\eta$ are countable. Since $\omega_1$ is not countable, it cannot be written that way.

---

**Related:**

- [Do $\omega^\omega=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154985/do-omega-omega-2-aleph-0-aleph-1/)
- [Ordinal exponentiation - $2^{\omega}=\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318827/ordinal-exponentiation-2-omega-omega)
- [How is $\epsilon_0$ countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109206/how-is-epsilon-0-countable)
- [Is it true that $|\mathbb{R}|=2^\omega=\omega_1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593334/is-it-true-that-mathbbr-2-omega-omega-1)
- [How to define countability of $\omega^{\omega}$ and $\omega_1$? in set theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197863/how-to-define-countability-of-omega-omega-and-omega-1-in-set-theory)

Comment: *"if you give up, it has been asked on this site infinitely many times before"*
 How can it be infinitely many times?
Overall there are only finitely many questions on this forum.
I know this question is very old, but I always thought mathematicians wish to be precise about things.

Comment: I guess you also thought that mathematicians are devoid of sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

The topology of the Baire space $\omega^\omega$ is defined by the base of open subsets $O_s:=\{f\in\omega^\omega|f\succ s\}$ for $s\in\omega^n$ for some $n\geq 0$, where $f\succ s$ shall mean, that $s$ is a finite starting sequence of $f$. This is the product topology of the discrete topologies of the $\omega$.

You should carefully distinguish the finite sequences $s\in\omega^n$ (for some $n$) from the infinite sequences $f\in\omega^\omega$. The former may be used in definitions and arguments w.r.t. Baire space but are no elements of $\omega^\omega$.