# Ordinals, cardinals and how to understand $2^{\aleph_0}$ versus $2^{\omega_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have read that $2^{\omega_0}=2^{\omega}=\omega$. (in the sense that they have the same order type). On the other hand, I know that $\omega=\aleph_0$, since it is the least infinite countable ordinal. I also know that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1 = \omega_1$ which is the least uncountable ordinal. Doesn't this gives us $2^{\omega_0}=\omega_1$? So, which of the above facts that i have stated is not correct?

Thank you,

Also. if you find my question duplicated, I will be greatfull if you could mention where can i find the answer.

Comment: See all the links [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/598226/622).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ is not always true, this is independent of the ZFC axioms of set theory, and is known as the Continuum Hypothesis. What *is* true is that this is an uncountable cardinal, so $|\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0} \ge \aleph_1$.

As a set, $\omega = \aleph_0$ (in the usual set theoretic set-up), but just like addition is different for ordinals, so is exponentiation. When we write $\omega$, we mean to look at the set as an ordinal (i.e. having a specific well-order), and when we write $\aleph_0$ we mean to use it as a "yard-stick" for infinite sets. So $\omega+1 \neq \omega$ as ordered sets, but $\aleph_0 + 1 = \aleph_0$ as cardinals (they have the same size). Also, exponentiation is different, so the meaning of $2^\omega$ is some specific order type, and $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of the powerset of $\aleph_0$.

The operations $+$ and powers depend on the context. Also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) warns for the confusion and the different symbol uses.

Comment: I think I am begining to get it. Is the following statement correct? $2^\omega = lim\{2^n | n \in \omega\}$ and $2^{\aleph_0} = \{ f | f $ is a function from $\omega$ to $\{ 0,1 \}$ $ \}$.

Comment: Indeed, the definition of $2^\omega$ is the $\sup$ or limit of the set of ordinals $\{2^n: n \in \omega\}$, while $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the **cardinality** of the set of functions from $\omega$ to $2 = \{0,1\}$. This cardinality equals some $\aleph_\alpha$ (if we assume the axiom of choice, which I do). Exactly which $\alpha$ is undetermined by the axioms.